# JSON.Net deserialize particular object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm using JSON.Net in the trial to serialize/deserialize a not-so-well-formed JSON.

Specifically I'm trying to serialize an attribute with a js variable as value, something like this:

```
{ ..., mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, ... }
```

My c# classes are

```
public enum MapTypeId
{
    HYBRID, ROADMAP, SATELLITE, TERRAIN
}

[JsonObject]
public class MapOptions
{
    ...

    [JsonProperty]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MapTypeConverter))]
    public MapTypeId mapTypeId { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

With a custom `JsonConverter` I've been able to control the serialization:

```
public class MapTypeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    ...

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteRawValue("google.maps.MapTypeId." + ((MapTypeId)value).ToString());
    }

    ...
}
```

And the serialization works. But when I'm trying to deserialize the string with:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MapOptions>(ser);
```

I get the error: `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: g. Path 'mapTypeId', line 1, position 169.`

In my MapTypeConverter I've also tryed to override the ReadJson method:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    // no parse by now, just a try
    return MapTypeId.TERRAIN;
}
```

without luck.

Suggestions?